# How to visualize a graph made with igraph in C?

Tags: c, plot, igraph

I started to learn igraph in C and I was wondering how can I visualize a graph made with this library. I've seen that with igraph R one just use the plot function and the graph is plotted but if I use C, should I print the graph in a file and then use another program to visualize it or which is the usual way?

Thanks!

edit: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) kind of graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot directed graphs try GraphViz (https://www.graphviz.org).

Alternatively you could use a tool like Gephi (https://gephi.org) if you are willing to write the data into a file in a manner compliant with one of their supported formats (https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/). GML looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: I mean this kind of graphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You could give graphviz a shot. They have some c examples in their documentation page. https://www.graphviz.org/documentation/

Comment: I also discovered this tool for visualizing graphs, https://gephi.org/, but I think I may be going of in the weeds a liitle. You'd have to figure out how to generate data this thing can understand.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy), and have your program output the description of the graph (in text format, or in an easily processed form if no pure text format is easily available).

(Note that this also applies to image formats; the NetPBM (.pnm, or .pbm, .pgm, and .ppm) formats are easy to generate in pure C (to e.g. standard output), and if necessary, the NetPBM tools can be used to convert to any other image format you might wish.)

For example, if your program outputs

```
graph {
    rankdir=LR;
    "6" -- "4";
    "4" -- "5";
    "3" -- "4";
    "3" -- "2";
    "5" -- "2";
    "5" -- "1";
    "2" -- "1";
}
```

then redirecting the output to e.g. `output.dot` and running `dot -Tx11 output.dot` will output a graph similar to the one shown in the [Wikipedia Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) article,

[image: Undirected graph]

---

You mention that you are using igraph, and luckily this library already supports writing graphs in the DOT format. See [the `igraph_write_graph_dot()` function](https://igraph.org/c/html/latest/igraph-Foreign.html#igraph_write_graph_dot).

---

The DOT language is specified [here](https://www.graphviz.org/documentation/), but it really is quite simple. `--` denotes an undirected edge, and `->` a directed edge. The `rankdir=LR;` line is a graph attribute, and tells DOT that it should try to order the nodes seen from left to right. The default is from top to bottom. You can add node attributes too, for example `"6" [ label="Six" ];` would change the label of node `"6"` to `Six`. Edge attributes work exactly the same way; so using `"2" -- "1" [ taillabel="Z" ];` adds "Z" near node "2" end of the edge between nodes "2" and "1". It is best to quote node names, even though the quotes are not necessary if the node name starts with a letter and does not match a graph attribute name.

---

Here is a useful hint, when printing trees or linked lists:

Use `%p` (a pointer to the node) as the node name, and `label="value"` to set the visible label of the node to `value`. For example, if you have

```
struct node {
    struct node  *left;
    struct node  *right;
    int           value;
};
```

then a simple function pair,

```
void print_tree_recursive(FILE *out, struct node *curr)
{
    fprintf(out, "    \"%p\" [ label=\"%d\" ];\n", (void *)curr, curr->value);
    if (curr->left) {
        print_tree_recursive(out, curr->left);
        fprintf(out, "    \"%p\" -> \"%p\" [ taillabel="L" ];\n", curr, curr->left);
    }
    if (curr->right) {
        print_tree_recursive(out, curr->right);
        fprintf(out, "    \"%p\" -> \"%p\" [ taillabel="R" ];\n", curr, curr->right);
    }
}

void print_tree(FILE *out, struct node *tree)
{
    fprintf(out, "digraph {\n");
    if (tree)
        print_tree_recursive(out, tree);
    fprintf(out, "}\n");
    fflush(out);
}
```

will print a nice directed graph of any tree. It is easy to modify to print linked lists (both singly and doubly linked). Note how the helper function describes the node first (the fprintf with `label=`), and the edges separately (the fprintfs with `taillabel=`).

If you print the graph to standard output, you can either redirect the output to a file and display or convert it using `dot -Tformat filename`, or you can pipe the output directly to `| dot -Tx11` to see the generated graph.

I frequently use the Graphviz DOT format for checking whether my mental picture of data structure linkage matches the reality. I find it an extremely useful tool, and keep recommending it for anyone working with complex data structures.

Comment: I hope you're okay with my edit. OP says they are using igraph and I added information about how to export to Graphviz format from igraph.