# Print Binary Tree in C

Tags: c, printf, binary-tree

How can i display an binary tree in c?,
like this

```
         37
      /      \
    16        3
   /  \       / \
  9   26    58  81
        \   / \
        35 55  74
```

i can display level by level

1
23
4567
89

but i need draw this BTs in the exactly format

```
void printLevel(NoArvore * node , int level)
{
  if(node != NULL && level == 0)
  {
  printf("%d",node->number);
  printf("====");
  }
  else if(node != NULL){

    printLevel(node->left,level-1);
    printLevel(node->right,level-1);
  }
}

void printElements(NoArvore *node)
{
  int i,spaces;
  int levelCount = getHeight(node);
  int Hspace =  getHeight(node);

  for(i = 0; i < levelCount;i++)
  {
    for(spaces = 0; spaces <= (Hspace*Hspace)-(i+3);spaces++)
     printf("=");
    printLevel(node,i);
    printf("\n");
  Hspace--;
  }
}
```

with this code, i have this output

```
==============37====
======16====76====
9====26====58====81====
35====55====74====
```

Comment: Describe how you created the desired output, line by line. If you can do that, you are one step closer to programming it. By the way, consider using a different representation, the one in your desired output is unpleasant at the line between 1 and 3, the touching 5 and  6, the branch from 5 not starting at 5 and the leaf connected to 5 being beneath the 6.

Comment: If you can describe how to do the prettier representation you will find out that you need to know the depth and the width of the total tree even before you print the first line.

Comment: The 'desired' output is pretty ugly.  It looks like you dropped at least one space in the lower levels.  What output do you want if node 6 has both left and right children?  Only a left child?  Only a right child?  Similarly for node 5?  In all combinations of 5 and 6 having children. What output do you want if the tree has four full levels and a fifth partially full level?

Comment: @Yunnosch : Between 1 and 3 the \ simply had one too many spaces - fixed.

Comment: This output is wrong, I use symbols to count spaces, but I'm trying to this                                
        1
        / \
       2   3
      / \ / \
     4   56  7
         \ \
          8 9

Comment: Your ASCII representation will not work generally (i,e, for any arbitrary tree) - for example if node 6 had a left branch, where would it go?  It cannot easily be done top-down,  the spacing in the upper layers is determined by the number of layers, and you cannot "draw" lines between nodes without also insering a number of additional lines to get the separation. It is easier to do left-right as described [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/23/visualizing-binary-trees-with-graphviz).  This same article goes on to show how to do it graphically much more satisfactorily using graphviz.

Comment: @Clifford if node 6 has a left branch , i can use spaces , just using the format , with / \ representing the branch each with own node. i just need the format but i can use more spaces

Comment: @ezequiel : In that case, your example is poor.  With out a consistent specification of what you expect in the output you cannot code it.  Code that output _exactly_ what you have proposed would be incorrect - you "tweaked" it to make it _kind of_ work, and that is not conducive to software implementation.

Comment: with this input 37 16 26 76 58 9 74 35 81 55  i want this output

Comment: i go update my example

Comment: If you try and draw a tree that _works_ manually using consistent rules that could be coded, you will find it very difficult.  I tried, and it would need the use of vertical `|` connectors, but defining the rules defeated me.  And it gets wors when the nodes are not single characters.  It does not seem very practical.  I'd go with graphviz.

Comment: Graphviz -- that is, outputting only the description of the graph in the DOT language from your program, and using one of the Graphviz tools to draw the actual graph based on the description -- is definitely the way to go. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631094/1475978) for an actual, working example.